# Creating software function index

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, glossaries

I need to create some type of index for exported functions in the software for the latex manual. The doxygen feature of exporting to LaTeX does not allow to do it by default.
The required form is following:

Index:
[function name], [function description] ....... [page]

_other functions

Text:

[function name[
    [function description]
[additional information(function parameters, return type and so on...]

Traditional index package have no possibility to add custom description to the index however (or I have not looked thoroughly?) Or the glossaries package has the required functionality?

Here is file example:

```
GetOperationState %function name
function returns the actual state of measurement. %function description
%below is additional information
\begin{verbatim}
unsigned short GetOperationState(unsigned short Op) 
\end{verbatim}
Parameters 
\begin{description}
    \item{Op}  Reserved for future use. 
\end{description}
Return Values 
...Some Text...
```

Please help or give the direction of where to look.

Comment: You could do it in a normal index (basically you make the function name the hidden sort key and put everything  as the index entry) or glossaries would probably help, but if you are generating a file with a list of such entries, a few lines of perl (or awk or python or elisp) would just re-order the file before you gave it to latex, which might be easier.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx by the way:-) Do you mean an _index_ (re-sorted alphabetical listing, normally at end of the document) or do you mean a _table of contents_ (called an index in some non-english languages) which is in document order, and normally at the front of the document?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- this sounds a lot like the (wonderful) command summary in kopka & daly, appendix g.  but i don't know how they created it.

Comment: Please,sorry for the lack of english terminology. it's definitely like table of contents, but with comments

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, that's very similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I think you mean something like this, which is just using `\@starttoc` which underlies `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures`

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textheight{30\baselineskip}

\makeatletter

\def\FunName#1#2#3{%
\par
\vskip 2\baselineskip plus 1fil\penalty-200\vfilneg
\noindent\hskip-5em\label{Fun-#1}\textbf{#1}%
\addcontentsline{fun}{fun}{{#1}{\detokenize{#3}}}%
\par
\nopagebreak
\noindent\ignorespaces#3\par}

\def\l@fun#1{\l@@fun#1}
\def\l@@fun#1#2#3{%
\par\noindent\parbox[t]{.3\textwidth}{#1}\quad
\parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{\small\raggedright#2}\dotfill
#3\par}


\def\FunctionListing{%
\section*{Function Listing}%
\@starttoc{fun}}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\FunctionListing

\FunName{GetOperationState} %function name
\FunDesc{function returns the actual state of measurement.} %function description
%below is additional information
\begin{verbatim}
unsigned short GetOperationState(unsigned short Op) 
\end{verbatim}
Parameters 
\begin{description}
    \item{Op}  Reserved for future use. 
\end{description}
Return Values 
...Some Text...

\FunName{SetOperationState} %function name
\FunDesc{function sets the actual state of measurement.} %function description
%below is additional information
\begin{verbatim}
unsigned short SetOperationState(unsigned short Op) 
\end{verbatim}
Parameters 
\begin{description}
    \item{Op}  Reserved for future use. 
\end{description}
Return Values 
...Some Text...



\FunName{GetSomething} %function name
\FunDesc{function does something interesting.} %function description
%below is additional information
\begin{verbatim}
unsigned short GetSomething(
        unsigned short Opa,
        unsigned short Opb,
        unsigned short Opc}
\end{verbatim}
Parameters 
\begin{description}
    \item{Opa}  Reserved for future use. 
    \item{Opb}  Reserved for future use. 
    \item{Opc}  Reserved for future use. 
\end{description}
Return Values 
...Some Text...



\end{document}
```

Comment: That's is the needed thing, thanks! But there's one more question - where is \FunDesc macro defined?

Comment: Sorry I should have commented on that, it's not defined at all. I needed FunName to have access to the description so it could write to the table of contents file. I probably should have made it just take two arguments the name and description but since I already had the example markup with \FunDesc I made \FunName take three arguments but not use #2 (\FunDesc)